# How does the ring $\mathbb R[x] / (x^2 - 1)$ work?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am new to ring theory and so some of its concepts are still not clear to me. One of them being the quotient rings. 
Let's say that I needed to construct this ring: $$\mathbb R[x] / (x^2 - 1)$$ 
The ring of polynomials with real coefficients "quotiented" by the ideal generated by the polynomial $(x^2 - 1)$. 
 
Let $C$ be the set of  cosets of the ideal. Then:
$$C = \{p + (x^2-1) : p \in \mathbb R[x] \}$$
Now, consider this coset:
$$D = x^3 + (x^2-1) = x^3 + kx^2 - k $$
And this
$$E = x^5 + (x^2-1) = x^5+kx^2-k$$ $$k \in \mathbb R$$
Therefore $$D+E = x^5 + x^4 +kx^2-k $$
Now, I know that the original ring only contains linear polynomials, and so my expression should somehow simplify. but I don't know how to do it. 
I can imagine why the multiples of $(x^2-1)$ will be sent to zero - they form the coset containing the natural element.  
But in my case the expression I got cannot be factored so that I can cancel anything but $(kx^2 - k)$ out. 
How do I simplify this? 
Although it may be inappropriate, please, could you give an answer in simple terms? I am not taking any course in abstract algebra, just some leisurely reading.

Comment: As an addition to the (correct) answer, in a quotient ring of a polynomial it's usually easiest to just write in representatives, so that $D = x^3$ and $E = x^5$, while keeping in mind that $x$ is no longer a "free variable"; it now obeys the rule $x^2 = 1$ (or equivalently $x^2 - 1 = 0$). If you stick to this way of writing/thinking about things it's obvious that $E = x^5 = x^2 \times x^2 \times x = x$.

Answer (score 3):

The set of cosets of the ideal $(x^2-1)$ is the set$$\{p(x)+(x^2-1)\,|\,p(x)\in\mathbb{R}[x]\}.$$Note that $p(x)$ can be polynomial with any degree, not just a linear one.

In particular, if $p(x)=x^3$, then the coset is$$\{x^3+(x^2-1)\,|\,p(x)\in\mathbb{R}[x]\}=\{p(x)+q(x)\times(x^2-1)\,|\,q(x)\in\mathbb{R}[x]\}.$$And here $q(x)$ can be *any* polynomial.

And if $p^\star(x)=x^5$, you can use the fact that$$x^5+x^3=(x^3+2x)(x^2-1)+2x$$to deduce that, in $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2-1)$,$$\bigl(p(x)+(x^2-1)\bigr)+\bigl(p^\star(x)+(x^2-1)\bigr)=2x+(x^2-1).$$

Answer (score 2):

Since in this quitient ring you "divided out" the polynomial $x^2-1$, you set this polynomial equal to zero, that is

$$
x^2-1=0\Rightarrow x^2=1
$$

this means

$$
x^3=x
$$

and

$$
x^5=x.
$$

Hope this helps.

Comment: So this means that my target ring will have two divisors of zero: $(x-1)$ and $(x+1)$?

Comment: Since you can factor $x^2-1$ as $(x-1)(x+1)$ the answe is yes.